# When scrolling in my UITableView cells are disappearing

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is my sample twitter program it works but there are several errors 
if I scroll up or down top and bottom cellls disappears some times I get an error saying :

BAD ACCESS CODE this happens on this row

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Please Advice

[image]

```
#import "TableViewViewController.h"

@interface TableViewViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"tweets array count : %d", tweets.count);
    return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"ROW : %d", indexPath.row);

    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];

    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchTweets];
}

- (void)fetchTweets
{

    NSString *twitterURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json"];    
    NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:twitterURL];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fullURL options:0 error:&error];

    tweets  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL
                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                        error:&error];    
}

.....

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the answer My app doesn't support ARC because I didn't check if we use a retain at the NSJSONSerialization the error is fixed.

```
 tweets  = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL
                                                      options:kNilOptions
                                                        error:&error] retain];
```

Answer (score 3):

I see problems in this function:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"tweets array count : %d", tweets.count);
    //return tweets.count;
    return 11; //default returns 20 but only shows 10 indexpath.Row so 11
}
```

You probably shouldn't be just returning 11 -- what if `tweets` has a different length? The table view will try to fetch a cell at an index which doesn't exist in your array. Try returning `tweets.count` instead.

To elaborate a bit further: The purpose of the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method isn't to tell iOS how many rows there are on the screen, it's how many rows there are in the entire `tableView`. This includes cells which aren't shown on screen.

Comment: okay I returned twitter.count now I cannot scorall BAD ACCESS Error !

Comment: NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Add the exception breakpoint to your project, then you will be able to  get well defined error.

Answer (score 0):

Why is numberOfRowsInSection hardcoded to 11?

Also you should have [self.tableView reloadData] after the tweets array is set up in `fetchTweets`

Comment: I am using a UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: that isn't relevant to what i suggested, so what are you trying to say? As far as I can tell currently, the tableview will have no way of knowing that the array has been updated once the tweets have been fetched.

Comment: Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'TableViewViewController *'

Comment: Oh i see what you mean. I thought you were using an actual TableViewController. just replace tableView with whatever your UITableView property is called. where is the tableView instance that is actually being used?

Comment: There's no instance declared in interface ! I dragged and droped a UITableView control into a SingleViewBased Application and coded ? 

so if I add an instance and a property for my tableView & then tableview reloadData function, i tried still the cells are disappearing when scrolling & crash

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just uncomment `return tweets.count;` in your `numberOfRowsInSection` method?